# Konva - select and save shapes

Tags: javascript, konva

I'm going to use konva.js to draw and select shapes in a canvas, but I'd like to save into mysql database the type of shapes selected (square1, rectangle2, etc). How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: Hello. SO is here to help you a specific problems, not to do the job for you. Try to achieve your goal. If you struggle on something, come back again with a clear description of the problem, the expected output and the actual output.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `stage.toJSON()` ? Here is the [Doc](https://konvajs.org/docs/data_and_serialization/Serialize_a_Stage.html)